# Contador de vocales mediante métodos

Tags: java

Tengo que realizar un programa al que se le pasa una palabra y éste tiene que contar las vocales que tiene.

Las palabras se pasan llamando al método `getCount(String str)`. De momento lo que hago es recorrer las letras de la palabra con un `for`, pero me da errores.

Os dejo mi código:

```
public class Vocales {

  public static int getCount(String str) {
    palabra = getCount(str);
    int contadorVocales = 0;
    for (int i = 0, i < palabra.length, i++) {
      if ((palabra.charAt(x)=='a') || (sPalabra.charAt(x)=='e') || (sPalabra.charAt(x)=='i') || (sPalabra.charAt(x)=='o') || (sPalabra.charAt(x)=='u')){ 
        contadorVocales++;
      }
    }
    
    return contadorVocales;
  }

}
```

Comment: ¿Podrías indicar exactamente el error que te da? "Me da errores" es una descripción muy vaga y no ayuda nada. A simple vista es muy probable que donde pone `palabra = getCount(str);` esté provocando un bucle de llamadas recursivas infinito que termine desbordando la pilla.

Comment: Además, la variable `palabra` no está definida, el bucle `for` está mal porque los separadores son dos puntos, no comas, etc, luego intentas acceder a `palabra` como si fuera un `String` cuando tu función devuelve un entero, intentas acceder a su posición en `palabra` y `spalabra`, accedes a `charAt(x)` usando `x` en vez de `i`, etc... Tu código está lleno de errores.

Answer (score 3):

Tienes múltiples fallos en el código:

- Usas un bucle usando como índice `i` pero luego intentas acceder a los elementos usando `x`.
- Estás llamando de manera recursiva a tu propia función, entrando en un bucle de llamadas infinito que desborda la pila.
- El parámetro de la función es `str` pero no lo usas en ningún momento, solo `palabra`.
- La variable `palabra` no está definida, parece contener un entero, que es lo que devuelve la llamada a la función que hace, pero luego se accede a su contenido a través de métodos de `String` (con `charAt()`).
- Intentas obtener la longitud de una cadena usando un atributo `length`, que no existe en `String`, en vez del método `length()`.
- Haces uso de la variable `sPalabra` como si existiera o hubiera sido definida previamente.
- El bucle `for` usas como separador comas (`,`) en vez de puntos y comas (`;`).
- Compruebas solo las vocales minúsculas. O compruebas también las mayúsculas o previamente debes convertir toda la cadena a minúsculas.

---

El código corregido podría ser el siguiente:

```
public class Vocales {
    /* Main de ejemplo para reproducir el problema */
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        String frase = "Hola A todOs";
        System.out.println("Vocales en la frase: " + getCount(frase));
    }
    
    public static int getCount(String str) {
        /* Convertimos a minúsculas la cadena entregada */
        String minusculas = str.toLowerCase();
        int contadorVocales = 0;
        /* Iteramos por cada carácter de la cadena */
        for (int i = 0; i < minusculas.length(); i++) {
            /* Comprobamos si es cada una de las vocales (en minúscula) */
            if (
                (minusculas.charAt(i) == 'a')
                || (minusculas.charAt(i) == 'e')
                || (minusculas.charAt(i) == 'i')
                || (minusculas.charAt(i) == 'o')
                || (minusculas.charAt(i) == 'u')
            ) {
                /* Si es una, incrementamos la cuenta */
                contadorVocales++;
            }
        }
        /* Devolvemos el resultado de la cuenta */
        return contadorVocales;
    }
}
```

Comment: Solamente quisiera recalcar una vez más para el OP que ***copiar y pegar código sin mirarlo y ENTENDERLO*** no sirve de nada. Es mejor intentar hacerlo y no poder que copiar y pegar código que no se entiende!

Answer (score 2):

Añado otra forma de hacerlo para evitar ese `if` haciendo uso de [`List.contains()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#contains(java.lang.Object)):

```
public class Main {

    private static final List<Character> vocales = Arrays.asList('a', 'e', 'i', 
     'o', 'u');

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String frase = "Vocales";
        System.out.println("El numero de vocales es: " + contarVocales(frase));
    }
    private static int contarVocales(String frase){
        frase = frase.toLowerCase();
        int numVocales = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < frase.length(); i++){
            if (vocales.contains(frase.charAt(i))){
                numVocales ++;
            }
        }
        return numVocales;
    }

}
```

Pero de igual manera revisa el otro comentario para ver los fallos.

Comment: Mi +1 por la mejora.

Answer (score 0):

```
  public static void main(String[] args) 
  {
    List<Character> vocales = Arrays.asList('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u');        
    String palabra = "Hola";
    List<String> list = Arrays.asList(palabra);
    list.retainAll(vocales);                 
  }
```

Para resolver lo que dices te propongo usar la interseccion entre conjuntos. Aqui primero creamos la lista de vocales y la palabra a la que vamos a analizar la convertimos en una lista donde cada elemento de esta lista se corresponde a cada caracter de esta palabra.

Posteriormente invocamos al metodo retainAll. Este metodo se utiliza para eliminar todos los elementos de un conjunto que no estan en otro.

En nuestro caso tenemos:

```
list.retainAll(vocales);
```

Donde se va a eliminar todos los elementos de list que no esten en vocales. El resultado seria que ahora list tendria solamente los elementos 'o' y 'a', ya que 'h' y 'l' no se encuentran en vocales

Referencia:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/arraylist-retainall-method-in-java/